# Is a normed vector space with an isometry group acting transitively on its unit ball an inner product space?

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, normed-spaces, clifford-algebras

In section 2.3 of [The Octonions](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/octonions.pdf), Baez discusses a proof for the Hurwitz theorem on normed division algebras via Clifford algebras that goes through the following argument. Supposing that $\mathbb K$ is a normed division algebra, and $a \in \mathbb K$ with $\Vert a\Vert = 1$, the operators

$$ L_a : \mathbb K \rightarrow \mathbb K\\\qquad\, x\mapsto ax$$

are norm-preserving and map any point of the unit sphere to any other point (because $\mathbb K$ is assumed to be a division algebra). Baez then writes that “the only way the unit sphere in $\mathbb K$ can have this much symmetry is if the norm on $\mathbb K$ comes from an inner product”.

Is it true that a normed vector space must in fact be an inner product space if there is a group of isometries acting transitively on its unit sphere? If so, how so? If not, did Baez mean something else?

Comment: Is your vector space real and finite dimensional? Then the answer is positive.

Comment: I think, Baez assumes (implicitly?) both properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert my comments to an answer:

I will assume that your normed division algebra $K$ is real and finite-dimensional. I am nearly sure that Baez assumes both.

Lemma. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real normed vector space. Suppose that the subgroup $G$ of linear isometries of $K$ acts transitively on the unit sphere of the norm on $V$. Then the norm on $V$ comes from an inner product.

Proof. Let $B$ denote the (closed) unit ball of the norm of $V$. Then $B$, as any compact convex solid in $V$,  admits the **[Jones ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid)** which is the unique least volume ellipsoid containing $B$. (A formal definition of a closed ellipsoid is that it is the unit ball of a norm given by an inner product.) By the uniqueness of $E$, the group $G$ preserves $E$. But then $G$ also preserves the (nonempty) set of points where the boundaries of $B$ and $E$ meet. By the transitivity assumption, it then follows that $\partial B=\partial E$, i.e. $B=E$. Hence, $B$ comes from an inner product. qed

Edit. According to the survey by Pelczynski and Bessaga,

[Some aspects of the present theory of Banach spaces](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/or/or2/or214.pdf), page 255,

the above lemma is a result due to Auerbach and von Neumann (independently). At the same time, according to the same source, if $\mu$ is a non-sigma-finite non-atomic measure, then for each $p\in [1,\infty)$, the Banach space $V=L^p(\mu)$ has the property that the group of linear isometries acts transitively on the unit sphere. (I did not check this.) In this example, the Banach space $V$ is not a Hilbert space. It is an open problem, due to Banach and Mazur if every **separable** Banach space whose group of linear isometries acts transitively on the unit sphere is necessarily a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick argument that came to my mind, though I am a little bit out of my comform zone with some statements (I highlighted them with a $\color{red}{??}$, and maybe someone more knowledgeable can correct or affirm me).

---

If $V$ is your (finite-dimensional, real) normed vector space with norm $\|\cdot\|$ and transitive symmetry group $G\subseteq\mathrm{GL}(V)$ on $S:=\{v\in V\mid\|v\|=1\}$, then $G$ is a *compact linear group* ($\color{red}{??}$).

I believe that it is a well-known fact ($\color{red}{??}$) from the representation theory of compact groups that there is a $G$-invariant inner product on $V$, that is, $\langle gv,gw\rangle_* = \langle v,w\rangle_*$ for all $v,w\in V$ and $g\in G$. Then, also the norm $\|v\|_*^2:=\langle v,v\rangle_*$ is $G$-invariant.

Set $\alpha:=\|v\|^2/\|v\|_*^2$ (which is independent of $v$ because both norms are $G$-invariant). Then $\langle v,w\rangle:=\alpha \langle v,w\rangle_*$ is an inner product to the norm $\|\cdot\|$ of $V$.

Comment: Yes, both ?? hold.

Comment: To prove compactness of the subgroup you can proceed in two steps: First verify that it is a closed subset of the set of all $n\times n$ real matrices $M(n,{\mathbb R})$. Then verify that it is a bounded subset (for instance, using the SVD). Then you either appeal to Cartan's theorem that closed subgroups of Lie groups are again Lie groups, thus, have a measure given by integration of a biinvariant volume form. Or directly appeal to Haar's theorem. Lastly, construct an invariant inner product by averaging. An alternative is to use Jones' ellipsoid which defines an invariant inner product.