# Relations between finite dimensional normed vector space and inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

This is from *A Course in Metric Geometry* by D. Burago, Y. Burago, and S. Ivanov, exercise 1.2.24 p.7.

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional normed vector space. Prove that $V$ is Euclidean if and only if for any two vectors $v,w\in V$ such that $|v|=|w|$, there exists a linear isometry $f:V\rightarrow V$ such that $|w|=|f(v)|$.

My question is that I have no idea to prove the "if". When $V$ is an inner product space, then the existence of $f$ is just linear algebra. I want to obtain something to solve the other direction.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Did you prove one way?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some work and explain precisely what stops you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202406

Comment: There is a comment in the list of errata to the book stating that "This exercise is not as obvious as claimed in the beginning of the chapter. It
deserves at least a hint."